# Access $this within PHP callback function

Tags: php, oop, methods, this

In the code below, I'm struggling to find a way of accessing the object reference variable $this inside the callback function 'cb'.  I'm getting the error

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

I would like to be able to call the method 'bold' from within the function 'cb'.

```
    <?php
    class Parser
    {
        private function bold($text)
        {
            return '<b>' . $text . '</b>';
        }

        // Transform some BBCode text containing tags '[bold]' and '[/bold]' into HTML
        public function transform($text)
        {
                function cb($matches)
                {
                    // $this not valid here
                    return $this->bold($matches[1]);
                }           

                $html = preg_replace_callback('/\[bold\]([\w\x20]*)\[\/bold\]/', 'cb', $text);
                return $html;       
        }           
    }

    $t = "This is some test text with [bold]BBCode tags[/bold]";

    $obj = new Parser();

    echo $obj->transform($t) . "\n";
    ?>
```

Comment: use self::bold instead $this->bold

Comment: You are aware in PHP - _named functions can never be nested!_ The parser does not throw an error because of anonymous functions. Instead it extracts it and puts it in global space. ;-/ It does not put it as a method of the class ;-/ imo, _never nest named functions / methods in PHP._ imo, It usually ends in confusion for the programmer. Just make it a method in the class?

Comment: @JorgeMejia tested - produces a similar error: `Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active` . But @fusion3k 's solution works

Comment: @RyanVincent  Thank you - I wasn't aware of that, and won't make that mistake again!

Comment: @tcdaly I see you're trying to process BBCodes, could you try my library for that https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable scope issue: inside `cb` function no extern variable/object/etc is visible.

Change your function to class method:

```
class Parser
{
    (...)
    private function cb( $matches )
    {
        return $this->bold( $matches[1] );
    }           
    (...)
}
```

And then modify your `preg_replace_callback` in this way:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback( '/\[bold\]([\w\x20]*)\[\/bold\]/', array( $this, 'cb' ), $text );
#                                                                 ====================
```

As alternative (on PHP>=5.4) you can use an anonymous function:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback
(
    '/\[bold\]([\w\x20]*)\[\/bold\]/', 
    function( $matches )
    {
        return $this->bold( $matches[1] );
    }, 
    $text
);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works.  Am I right in thinking the effect of `array( $this, 'cb' )` is to inject `$this` into method `cb` as a local variable?  If so, what's the reason for also needing to move function `cb` to make it a class method?

Comment: `array( $this, 'cb' )` doesn't  inject `$this` into `cb`; it is the way to call an object method instead of function. It means `( object, method )`.

Answer (score 0):

would this work for you?

```
public function transform($text)
{
    $html = preg_replace_callback('/\[bold\]([\w\x20]*)\[\/bold\]/', array($this, 'bold'), $text);
    return $html;       
}
```

you may need to move a bit more logic to the function `bold` because it will get an array of matches in this case.

Comment: Thank you.  I actually need to keep the functions `cb` and `bold` separate because I need to also call `bold` elsewhere (in my actual application, the function called `bold` here does something more complex).